# Is it possible to prevent the screen turning off when pressing the power button?

Tags: security, lock-screens, htc-one-x

I run an app on my handset which really needs the screen to remain on for it to function properly. The app already seems to attempt to keep the screen on as the screen timeout seems to be disabled when the app is running, but I can still turn the screen off by tapping the power button.

I do my best *not* to press the power button, but sometimes I do it by accident.

My question is, is there any way of stopping the power button from turning the screen off? Perhaps there is something the original app developer can do to disable this?

This is on an unrooted device. I'm on Android 4.1.1 , HTC Sense 4+ stock rom

Comment: The app can't disable the power button. That would be a security nightmare.

Comment: @DanHulme How about just requiring power button presses to be long-presses to be registered (or requiring confirmation, such as this app does with volume buttons:  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hourdb.volumelocker&hl=en )

Comment: That app doesn't intercept the calls, it just undoes them later. You could have an app that turns the screen back on after you turn it off, but I think that would just be annoying rather than helpful.

Comment: I'm tempted to quip that you should just put a tape the power button.

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent lock button from turning off you screen by altering your settings.

- Go to your settings
- Select `Security`
- Deselect the check box `Power button instantly locks`

[image: Screen security settings]

Comment: Hmm, I don't have that option. I'm on Android 4.1.1 , HTC Sense 4+ stock rom

Comment: I'm running stock 4.2.2 on a Galaxy Nexus, and I don't have that option either. Is it a custom ROM setting?

Comment: @TimScarborough I'm running stock 4.2.2 on a GSM Galaxy Nexus as well, but I do have that option. See the screenshot I've edited into Sid's answer.

Comment: The option only appears if **Screen lock** is not set to **None**. The screen *turns off* regardless of this setting: it only controls whether the lock screen activates when the power button is pressed, or only after the timeout.

Comment: @DanHulme sorry misread your comment and missed the "not"

Comment: On 5.0.1, this option is unavailable if the screen lock is set to **none** or **swipe**.